# Changing the value of nested field in react final form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-final-form

we are using React Final Form library, and want to change the value of nested field on user's selection.

It is basically Address form, where on selection of `Suburb`, I want to change `postcode` and `state`.
address is again a nested object in form.
My Dataset look like :-

```
{
  name: 'xyzx',
  address: {
    suburb: 'xx',
  },
}
```

I am passing following mutator

```
export const changeValueMutator: Mutator = ([name]: string[], state: MutableState, { changeValue }: Tools) => {
  console.log(state, name);
  changeValue(state, name, value => (value));
};
```

and calling it as

```
this.props.changeValue('address.suburb', item.suburb);
```

Answer (score 6):

Nested fields in `final-form` are referenced with dot notation.

https://github.com/final-form/final-form#field-names

```
<Field
    name="address.suburb"
    component="input"
    type="text"
    placeholder="Suburb"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from one of the test case in library

I corrected it by changing my mutator method as below (take newValue as second arg in first parameter array).
https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form/blob/379755c24570bf0e1cedaa2f6783e642d2e2b369/src/ReactFinalForm.d.test.tsx#L69

```
export const changeValueMutator: Mutator =
  ([name, newValue]: string[], state: MutableState, { changeValue }: Tools) => {
  console.log(state, name);
  changeValue(state, name, value => (newValue));
};
```

Answer (score -4):

You can try this, if

```
state = {
  json : {
    name: 'xyzx',
    address: {
    suburb: 'xx',
  },
}

this.state.json.address.suburb = "yy";
this.setState({json : this.state.json});
```

Comment: A good answer has a better explanation [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)